# What are tags like @param and @return in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, ide, intellij-idea

I've just started using IntelliJ IDEA for Java programming and I'm seeing tags (are they called tags?) like @param and @return. **What is the significance of these tags?** IntelliJ actually complains if I don't have those tags in my code!

What are the most important ones to know and what are they used for?

I couldn't find anything relevant in the IntelliJ documentation regarding these tags.

Comment: In the comments in the code, heh.

Comment: The required tags, and warning level, is a configurable inspection--just search for "javadoc" in the settings.

Comment: @Terribad The `@` character is used by both javadoc ("in the comments") and by java ("in the code"--annotations). If it's complaining about them missing in *both* places, something is likely horribly wrong.

Comment: @DaveNewton: I see, I didn't know that it served a purpose other than Javadoc. I am not familiar with how it is used in the code (outside of comments).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, they are called tags. If you see those tags in the comments, they are to document your method's parameters and return value.

They can be automatically processed to generate JavaDoc documentation. The generated documentation will be similar to the the [Java API Documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/). See [how to write doc comments for the JavaDoc tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html).

Comment: Thanks. By applying monkey-see monkey-do, I gather that the general format for a tag is @tag <TAB> variable_name_if_any <TAB> description.

Comment: Not tab, just whitespace. Also, just to make it explicit, these tags aren't specific to IntelliJ.

Comment: Are these tags useless in code created outside an IDE? That is, code created with a text editor and compiled on the command line?

Comment: @Terribad The tags are used by javadoc (as linked to) to create API documentation.